# iTC: Unable to delete already approved app

Tags: app-store-connect

I have an approved app per the guidelines, yet there is no "Delete App" button anywhere in iTunes Connect.

How can I delete this already approved app in iTunes Connect?

Answer (score 2):

If your app is in "Pending For Developer Release" state then you can cancel your build by going to

> ITC -> My Apps -> Your_app -> Versions

Here you can see the message from ITC like

> You can only edit some information while your version is pending
>   developer release. To edit all information, cancel this release.

And by clicking on "cancel this release" you can remove your build and app state will be "Developer Rejected".

If you want to remove your app from sale (stop selling app) then you need follow the steps given below:

> Go to ITC -> My Apps -> Your_app -> Pricing -> specific territories ->
>   Deselect all the countries

It will remove your app from sale and app will be in "Developer Removed From Sale" state.